# how to validate date null in mysql?

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

I'm working with MariaDB. when I try to show some result don't show me nothing.

```
select 
    if(fecha is null,'hello','bye') dat
from 
    table
```

[image]

I'm trying to show me some result, but I don't know how?

Comment: Is there at least 1 row in the table?

Comment: No, the table don't have any

Comment: your query checks if the column has a `NUL`, as you have no  rows it will not check anything

Comment: Well no rows = no result.  Non-existing rows are not considered to be NULL entities.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but how to show something?

Comment: do you just want a result that tells you if there are any rows?  or do you want a result for each row, or 1 result if there are no rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (fecha  VARCHAR(2))
> ```

> ```
> SELECT IF( COUNT(*) = 0 , 'Empty',`fecha`) FROM t1
> ```
>
> ```
> | IF( COUNT(*) = 0 , 'EMpty',`fecha`) |
> | :---------------------------------- |
> | EMpty                               |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=c54e8da22ed987411d95d89fef8566c9)*